# feature map generation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I need to generate feature map for my project. First I need to take the input image and convert it to intensity image. Then perform edge detection based on the standard deviation.

Then I have to calculate horizontal and vertical projection and then I have to generate feature map. I wrote the below code.

```
in_img=imread('ball.png');

yuv=rgb2hsv(in_img);
c=yuv(:,:,3); % i have used hsv conversion in hsv v channel gives intensity image
edge1=edge_std(c); %edge_std is based on the standard deviation formula given in the
%paper

ver=imfilter(edge1,[-1 0 1]);
%ver=sum1(edge1,1);
%hor=sum(edge1,2);
hor=imfilter(edge1,[-1 0 1]');

h_mean=mean2(hor);%horizontal threshhold
v_mean=mean2(ver);%vertical threshhold

hor(hor>=h_mean)=1;
ver(ver>=v_mean)=1;
bw=imadd(hor,ver);
imshow(bw),title('feature map');
```

output of the above code is this

[image: the output is here]

But the feature map of this input image is supposed to be like below
[image]

above feature map is generated from the below edge image

[image]

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here. Is my feature map generation wrong ?. If so then how to generate feature map? How can I get the output like above?

Please see the below algorithm. I do not know what is feature map and how to generate it. I am stuck in feature map generation.

Below algorithm is from one paper. They have shown the experimental result of that ball image.

Even the ball image also from that paper only I took print screen and saved it as .png image and used it in my code.

Please tell me what is feature map in this algorithm and how to generate it? What is the input? It's class (binary, gray scale, etc.)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also is horizontal projection and vertical projection is correct in my code?

When thresholding horizontal and vertical projection result will become binary image. So should I just make pixels below threshold 0 and retain other pixels unchanged and hence it will remain as gray scale image?

Comment: Post the ball picture. How did you choose the feature map generation method?

Comment: Firstly sorry for the late reply. I  have no exact idea how to generate feature map. In the paper it was given that " horizontal and vertical projections of the edge images are calculated and with the help of horizontal and vertical threshold other directional edges are removed.Horizontal and vertical edge images are combined and then feature map is generated". i just combined horizontal and vertical edge images and i thought result of that itself is feature map , but actually  it is not. and how to post images in comment? should i post it as  a separate question?

Comment: @Lokesh Firstly sorry for the late reply. I have no exact idea how to generate feature map. In the paper it was given that " horizontal and vertical projections of the edge images are calculated and with the help of horizontal and vertical threshold other directional edges are removed.Horizontal and vertical edge images are combined and then feature map is generated". i just combined horizontal and vertical edge images and i thought result of that itself is feature map , but actually it is not. and how to post images in comment? should i post it as a separate question?

Comment: you could add the image in the same question. go ahead and edit the question.